# Error connecting Node.js with Cassandra on windows virtual machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I'm having a problem connecting Node.js to Cassandra. The error I get is the following:

```
Error: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: Error socket was closed. See innerErrors.
```

I'm not sure what it means by innerErrors, is that a log of some sort? I'm new to Cassandra and Node.js so I'm not sure what's going on. I created an inbound rule for ports 9042 and 9160 which are the ports that Cassandra uses. I've got no issue connecting through CQLSH and DevCenter. I don't know if using a VM could be causing this.

This is the node.js code I'm using to test this, on some table I created:

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], keyspace: 'space'});
var query = "SELECT * FROM space_table";

client.execute(query, function(err, results) {
    assert.ifError(err); 
    console.log(result.rows[0].pk);
});
```

Here's what I'm using:

Windows 7 VM with Virtual Box, 
DataStax Community 2.1.9 and Node.js with the DataStax driver for Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug on the Node.js driver for Cassandra v2.2.0 that is fixed on the latest version.

Updating via `npm` should solve the issue.

---

**Original answer**

It looks like there is a [bug in cassandra-driver 2.2.0](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-165) ([fix here](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/pull/83)) that is causing this issue on Windows against Cassandra 2.1 or below.

Use driver version 2.1.2 until the fix is merged:

```
$ npm install cassandra-driver@2.1.2 --save
```

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. However, I already resorted to python, nonetheless, thank you for the answer. Had I known, I would have probably used Node.js.